# Why does opencv_traincascade fail with: "Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled"?

Tags: opencv3.0

What I have tried so far...

```
opencv_createsamples -info positive/positive.txt -vec positive.vec -w 100 -h 100 -num 2
opencv_createsamples -info negative/negative.txt -vec negative.vec -w 100 -h 100 -num 2
opencv_traincascade -vec positive.vec -data . -bg negative/negative.txt -numPos 1 -numNeg 1 -numStages 1 -w 100 -h 100

# outputs
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated. Cascade classifier can't be trained. Check the used training parameters.
```

How to train a HAAR model with very few positives? The goal is to track 2d images in 2d images.

Answer (score 1):

One of your arguments is "numpos" but per http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html, it should be "numPos" with a capital P.

Comment: Ty. I already noticed that. It was a copy paste of early tries.

Comment: Any reason, then, not to upvote it and mark it as correct?

Comment: This does not fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Per http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html#negative-samples negative samples can't be created by createsamples. Unfortunately, the documentation is not super clear about why you can't, and the question hasn't been clear about what you expect this to do.